# software center not loading in 16.04

Tags: 16.04, software-center

that's pretty much it. Opening software center works with the 'all' tab loading fine, but when I try to search anything or access any other tabs it has an eternal loading screen.
I am running a recently updated ubuntu 16.04 on a 64 bit computer if that helps.

I tried the solution of similar problems in older versions of Ubuntu but they don't have any effect.

when I run software center from the terminal I get this:

```
zephyzu@zephyzu:~$ software-center
/usr/bin/software-center:25: PyGIWarning: Gtk was imported without specifying a version first. Use gi.require_version('Gtk', '3.0') before import to ensure that the right version gets loaded.
  from gi.repository import Gtk, GObject
/usr/share/software-center/softwarecenter/ui/gtk3/views/purchaseview.py:29: PyGIWarning: WebKit2 was imported without specifying a version first. Use gi.require_version('WebKit2', '4.0') before import to ensure that the right version gets loaded.
  from gi.repository import WebKit2 as webkit
/usr/share/software-center/softwarecenter/ui/gtk3/widgets/symbolic_icons.py:23: PyGIWarning: PangoCairo was imported without specifying a version first. Use gi.require_version('PangoCairo', '1.0') before import to ensure that the right version gets loaded.
  from gi.repository import Gtk, Gdk, GLib, PangoCairo
2016-05-28 14:21:23,340 - softwarecenter.ui.gtk3.app - INFO - setting up proxy 'None'
2016-05-28 14:21:24,079 - softwarecenter.backend.reviews - WARNING - Could not get usefulness from server, no username in config file
2016-05-28 14:21:24,082 - softwarecenter.plugin - INFO - activating plugin '<module 'webapps_activation' from '/usr/share/software-center/softwarecenter/plugins/webapps_activation.pyc'>'
2016-05-28 14:21:24,119 - softwarecenter.db.pkginfo_impl.aptcache - INFO - aptcache.open()
2016-05-28 14:21:24,905 - softwarecenter.db.update - WARNING - failed to load file /var/lib/apt-xapian-index/cataloged_times.p: unsupported pickle protocol: 3
/usr/share/software-center/softwarecenter/ui/gtk3/widgets/videoplayer.py:29: PyGIWarning: Gst was imported without specifying a version first. Use gi.require_version('Gst', '1.0') before import to ensure that the right version gets loaded.
  from gi.repository import Gst
/usr/bin/software-center:184: Warning: Source ID 70 was not found when attempting to remove it
  Gtk.main()
/usr/bin/software-center:184: Warning: Source ID 142 was not found when attempting to remove it
  Gtk.main()
2016-05-28 14:21:27,507 - softwarecenter.db.update - WARNING - failed to load file /var/lib/apt-xapian-index/cataloged_times.p: unsupported pickle protocol: 3
2016-05-28 14:21:28,779 - softwarecenter.db.utils - INFO - software-center-agent finished with status 0
```

Comment: tried the solution on that page and it still doesn't work

Comment: This question appears to be abandoned and unanswered. If you solved it, please post an answer explaining how it was solved (answering your own questions is not merely permitted, but [encouraged when there is no other answer that does the job](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/07/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/)). If the question no longer applies you may voluntarily delete/close it.

Answer (score 1):

---

You can install the classic "Software Center", which "always" works OK :

`$ sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install synaptic`

---

Comment: it works but it keeps freezing and progress is extremely slow

Comment: This does not explain how to fix the Software Center.

Answer (score 0):

There is something wrong with your APT Xapian index file:

```
2016-05-28 14:21:27,507 - softwarecenter.db.update - WARNING - failed to load file /var/lib/apt-xapian-index/cataloged_times.p: unsupported pickle protocol: 3
```

Move it to a different file:

```
sudo mv /var/lib/apt-xapian-index/cataloged_times.p /var/lib/apt-xapian-index/cataloged_times.p.backup
```

Force a rebuild:

```
sudo update-apt-xapian-index -f
```

Comment: mv: cannot stat '/var/lib/apt-xapian-index/cataloged_times.p': No such file or directory

Comment: So you don't even have a Xapian index. :D No problem, go on with the rebuild.

Comment: alrighty, done =) but the software center is still broken

Comment: @Zephyzu Does it give different errors now?